# Getting a Mean/Median/Mode/Quartile/Quantile in each column using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new in jupyter notebook and wondering how to get a quantile of a column inside a function:

DataFrame:

```
num_likes | num_post | ... | 
464.0     | 142.0    | ... |
364.0     | 125.0    | ... |
487.0     | 106.0    | ... |
258.0     | 123.0    | ... |
125.0     | 103.0    | ... |
```

myFunction:

```
def myFunction(x):
    q22 = dataframe["num_likes"].quantile(0.22)
    q45 = dataframe["num_likes"].quantile(0.45)
    qc = q45 - q22
    k = 3

    if x >= q45 + k * qc:
        return q45 + k * qc
    elif x <= q22 - k * qc:
        return q22 - k * qc
```

Right now, since I don't know how to get it, I ended up running the function for each column that I have. Also, I tried to run it and it seems that it is not working

```
data["num_likes"].apply(lambda x : myFunction(x))[:5]
```

Also, the result seems to be wrong as I didn't see the any returns

```
    num_likes | num_post | ... | 
    NaN       | None     | ... |
    NaN       | None     | ... |
    NaN       | None     | ... |
    NaN       | None     | ... |
    NaN       | None     | ... |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `None` is because no paths of your `if-elseif` block return true so `myFunction` is returning `None`. Did you mean `if-else`?

Besides that to clean up what you have I would do things a little bit different. First q22, q45, and qc only need to be calculated once (based on logic above) and these can be passed into the function instead calculated each time in the function. Second you do not need to create a `lambda` in this situation, `apply` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)) takes a python callable (your function) and one can pass additional arguments like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num_likes': [464.0, 364.0, 487.0, 258.0, 125.0],
    'num_post': [142.0, 125.0, 106.0, 123.0, 103.0]
})

def myFunction(x, q22, q45, qc):
    k = 3

    if x >= q45 + k * qc:
        return q45 + k * qc
    elif x <= q22 - k * qc:
        return q22 - k * qc
    else:
        return -1

q22 = df["num_likes"].quantile(0.22)
q45 = df["num_likes"].quantile(0.45)
qc = q45 - q22

# pass additional arguments in an tuple, they will be passed to myFunction
df.num_likes.apply(myFunction, args=(q22, q45, qc))

# this will return a series which can be assigned to new column
# 0   -1
# 1   -1
# 2   -1
# 3   -1
# 4   -1
# Name: num_likes, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to check the range of my quantiles first before posting, hence wondered why I cannot get the result I want. I can now understand the flaws in myFunction, thank you for pointing everything out. I just have a question, how did the function understand  that "x" is for each element in the column within passing it in the myFunction?

Comment: It is because `my_series.apply(myFunc)` is the logical equivalent of `for item in series: myFunc(item)` that is by default it will iterate passing the next item for all items in the series. Similarly if you do something like `df.groupby('num_likes').apply(myFunc)` than the first argument passed to `myFunc` is a dataframe (the one grouped by groupby)